# Exception when generating greenDao with String Primary Key

Tags: android, greendao

On compilation of greendao classes, I have an exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Source properties do not match target properties

```
      private static void addMainSchema(Schema schema) {


        Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");
        user.addIdProperty();
        user.addStringProperty("userName").unique().primaryKey();
        user.addStringProperty("firstname");
        user.addStringProperty("lastname");
        user.addStringProperty("phone");
        user.addStringProperty("secretKey");
        user.addStringProperty("wifiPassword");
        user.addStringProperty("stepLength");
        user.addStringProperty("password");
}
```

Comment: Please, even if you solved your question yourself you should provide more information on what you wnated to do, what was the exact problem and finally you should ask a question. Otherwise this won't be of any help anybody else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case:
It is appear when IdProperty has been set before primary key.
Fix: removing IdProperty.

```
 //    user.addIdProperty();

 user.addStringProperty("userName").unique().primaryKey();
```